# How to understand Euler's criterion for exactness of differential equation as presented in the book "Physical chemistry" by Silbey, Alberty, Bawendy?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

While reading a chapter about thermodynamics in a book, I encountered a small section on exact and inexact differentials. Since the book is a chemistry book, I am not sure if the math details/assumptions are being partially omitted from the reader.

Says the book,

> There is a simple test to see whether a differential is exact.
>
> For a system with just two independent degrees of freedom, the total
> differential $dz$ of a quantity $z$ may be determined by the
> differentials $dx$ and $dy$ in two other quantities $x$ and $y$. In
> general,
>
> $$dz=M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy\tag{2.17}$$
>
> where $M$ and $N$ are functions of the independent variables $x$ and
> $y$.
>
> To show the test for exactness we now consider a function $z$ that has
> an exact differential. If $z$ has a definite value at each point in
> the $xy$-plane, then it must be a function of $x$ and $y$. If
> $z=f(x,y)$, then
>
> $$dz=\left (\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right )_ydx +\left
>  (\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right )_x dy\tag{2.18}$$
>
> Comparing (2.17) and (2.18) we find
>
> $$M(x,y)=\left (\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right )_y\tag{2.19}$$
>
> $$N(x,y)=\left (\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right )_x\tag{2.20}$$
>
> Since the mixed partial derivatives are equal,
>
> $$\left [ \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left (\frac{\partial
>  z}{\partial x}\right )_y\right ]=\left [ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}
>  \left (\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right )_x \right ]\tag{2.21}$$
>
> then
>
> $$\left (\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\right )_x=\left (\frac{\partial
>  N}{\partial y}\right )_y\tag{2.22}$$
>
> This equation must be satisfied if $dz$ is an exact differential. It
> is Euler's criterion for exactness.

Here is what I think is being said, in my own words and with more assumptions made explicit.

(2.17) denotes a general differential. We don't know if it is exact or not. We wish to find some test that enables us to determine if this differential equation is exact or not.

Then we are given a function $z=z(x,y)$ that has, by assumption, an exact differential (equivalently, is differentiable).

The exact (total) differential of $z$ is

$$dz=\left (\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right )_ydx +\left
(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right )_x dy\tag{2.18}$$

It is stated that the mixed partial derivatives of $z$ are equal.

This occurs if $D_1 z$, $D_2 z$, and one of the mixed partial derivatives exist and, in addition, the mixed partial derivative is continuous in the open set $S$ that contains the point in consideration in this analysis. This is implicit in the snippet.

The snippet contains two conditions for the functions $M(x,y)$ and $N(x,y)$.

1. $M$ and $N$ are the partial derivatives of some function (called $z$ as well, but I am going to call it $\varphi$)
2. The mixed partials of $\varphi$ are equal.

Euler's criterion for exactness seems to be stated as being requirement 2).

As far as I know, given $M$ and $N$, if all we know is that $D_2 M=D_1 N$, then all we have is a necessary condition for $\langle M, N \rangle$ to be a gradient on an open set $S$ (unless the set $S$ is convex, in which case we have a sufficient condition).

My questions are: is my interpretation correct? Also, the way the book presents all of this, doesn't 2) require 1) to be true? Shouldn't Euler's criterion be 1) and 2) together? What is Euler's criterion for exactness after all?

Comment: Yes, that is all correct. // If you already know 1., then you do not need 2., as it is automatic. You want to test if arbitrarily given functions form a gradient/derivarive. You could also integrate one of the functions and then compute its derivative to the other variable, that is, try to find the primitive directly and take success or failure of this attempt as the test.

Comment: Of course they are omitting the hypothesis of simple connectivity. You do not in fact need convexity, as you probably already know.

Comment: @TedShifrin at which point in the reasoning is that assumption used exactly?

Comment: To get from locally exact to globally exact on your domain. It means that the line integral of the (closed) differential form will be path-independent,